# Discrete maths.. whether the statement is valid

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is the following argument valid? If Helen gets the supervisor’s position, then she’ll buy a new car. She has purchased a new car. Therefore, Helen did get the supervisor’s position.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. No. If it's raining, then the streets are wet. The streets are wet. Must it be raining? No. Maybe it was, but stopped. Maybe they just cleaned the streets. Or there was a flood.

Comment: What are your thoughts about that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: No unless it's stated to be an if and only if relationship.

Comment: NO; see the fallacy of [Affirming the consequent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent).

Comment: What if Helen won the lottery?

Comment: Is there anything stopping her from buying a new car whether she does or does not get the position?

Answer (score 0):

It is fallacy

$p\implies q $, q need not imply p

an argument is valid whenever all the premises are true then conclusion is also true but in truth table of $p\implies q$ both $p\implies q$ and $q$ are true but p is false.