# Discrete maths... Is this a valid argument??

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider the following argument:  If you read a lot, you will become a brilliant conversationalist. If you become a brilliant conversationalist, you will have many friends. Therefore, if you don’t have many friends, you don’t read a lot. Is this a valid argument?

\begin{array}{ccc|ccc}
P&Q&R&Statement_1&Statement_2&Statement_3\\
\hline
T&T&T&?&?&?\\
T&T&F&?&?&?\\
...\\
\end{array}

Comment: What are your thoughts? Between this and [your prior question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815644/discrete-maths-whether-the-statement-is-valid) it looks like you are just posting your homework here for us to do for you.

Comment: @lulu I'm new to this and didn't know how to post the truth table here

Comment: @user569043 I included the format of a truth-table .. you do the rest please! Same for your other Posts .. thanks!

Comment: Well.... yes.  It seems if you read a lot it is inevetable you will have many friends.  so to not have many friends you must not have read much.

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid argument, by Modus Tullens twice.

Let p be "one reads a lot". 
Let q be "one is a brilliant conversationalist". 
Let r be "one has many friends".

By MT, given "if p then q", or in English, "If one reads a lot, one is a brilliant conversationalist". If ~q, or, "one isn't a brilliant conversationalist", then ~p holds, or "one doesn't read a lot".

By MT for the second pair, and by the same line of logic, if one doesn't have many friends, one isn't a brilliant conversationalist. And by our first line of logic, if one isn't a brilliant conversationalist, one doesn't read a lot.

Therefore, if one doesn't have many friends, one doesn't read a lot.

Obviously in the real world, this could be false, but by the premises given, it is a valid conclusion.

Comment: You don't even have to use a truth table. If you have your rules of logic memorized, you could recognize Modus Tullens or Modus Ponens easily. It really helps to understand how they work.

Comment: thanks alot bro.. Really new to all this...

Comment: No problem. Truth tables really help with large problems dealing with whether something is a tautology, or when there are a lot of statements nested within each other where it would be hard to narrow it down to a couple logic rules.

Comment: Ok bro.... I've got another question I've worked on but I would like you to verify if what I'm doing is right ?